# Deleting a temporal Array in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

I was working with dynamic memory from a book that I got. As far as I understand every time that we create a *new* variable we need to delete it, and set the pointer to null, so we don't have *dangling pointers* .

I created a program that stores values from users in a dynamic Array of [5], and whenever the user adds more I "expand" the array. When expanding, I use a temporary new array that gives me a tough time when I try to delete it. Why does this happen?

```
size_t arraySize(5), index(0);

int inputvalue(0);
int *ptemporal(nullptr);

int *pvalues = new int[arraySize];

    for (;;){

        cout << "Enter value or 0 to end: ";
        cin >> inputvalue;  //enter value

        // exit loop if 0
        if (!inputvalue)  //if 0 break
            break;

        pvalues[index++] = inputvalue; //store values on pivalores

        if (index == arraySize){ //if limit reached create space

            cout << "Limit reached. Creating space...";

            arraySize += 5; //5 new memory blocks

            ptemporal = new int[arraySize]; //temporal value holder.

            for (size_t i = 0; i < arraySize - 5; i++)  //xfer values to temporal
                ptemporal[i] = pvalues[i];

                delete[] pvalues;       // delete values to  
                pvalues = ptemporal;  // assigning the same addres to pvalues.

                **delete[]  ptemporal; //causes a problem if I use the delete. if i comment the program works just fine.**

                ptemporal = nullptr;
        }


    }
return 0;
}
```

**The two asterics are just to show were the problem occurs.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? `std::vector` exists for exactly this purpose.

Comment: for training purposes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are deleting `ptemporal` right after you copy the pointer to `pvalues`:

```
pvalues = ptemporal; // assigning the same addres to pvalues.

delete[]  ptemporal; //causes a problem if I use the delete. if i commentt the program works just fine.**
```

In other words, you delete the memory you just created! So the next time you expand the vector, you try to delete it again, resulting in a double free error. This sort of error is where a debugger helps, so you can watch the variable values as your program executes.

```
// start
ptemporal = nullptr;
pvalues   = /* location A */;


// first expansion
ptemporal = /* location B */;
// copy values from location A to B
delete[]    pvales;    /* location A */
pvalues   = ptemporal; /* location B! */
delete[]    ptemporal; /* location B */
ptemporal = nullptr;


// second expansion
ptemporal = /* location C */;
// copy values from location B to C, should segfault

// then you delete pvalues (aka location B) again!
// this results in a double free error
delete[]    pvales;    /* location B */
```

To fix this, simply remove the line `delete[] ptemporal;`

Comment: Wow, thank you I believe I got it, so basically the crash comes when I delete for the second time the pvalues!?
thank you for your answers and everyones opinion :)

Comment: @JuanMar - It's possible that it will crash before that, since pvalues is pointing to deleted memory after the first expansion, but at least on my system it died on the second expansion when the code attempted to delete the same memory for a second time. If you count the number of `new[]` and `delete[]` per expansion its pretty obvious you only make one new array but delete two!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to delete pTemporal. You've deleted pValues and wish to hand over pTemporal into it.

```
delete [] pValues;
pValues = pTemporal;
pTemporal = NULL;
```

Comment: He (for whatever reason) crated the array on the heap. He has to delete it.

Comment: He also needs a 'delete pvalues;' at the end of the program outside the for loop and before the return statement, in order to free the last remaining array.